# Sonata Admin showing different dates

Tags: symfony4, sonata-admin

I'm working with Symfony and SonataAdmin. I created an Entity and Admin for a timeline. Everything works good, but the dates differ from differents views.

**Show** (wrong):

[image: Show]

**List** (wrong):

[image: List]

**Edit** (ok):

[image: Edit]

**DB** (real):

[image: DB]

```
$listMapper
    ...
    ->addIdentifier('fecha')

$formMapper 
    ...
    ->add('fecha', DatePickerType::class)


$showMapper
    ...
    ->add('fecha')
```

Comment: I never used these technologies but this error is common in most programming languages. Are you using zoned date objects? Timezones, sometimes mess up dates. If that was it, please expand the comment to an answer explaining what was wrong.

Comment: Can you show the used Entity file?

Comment: One of the fields is using Browser timezone info, the other one is using the server timezone and probably that's the reason. Try to change your PC timezone to match the server one. If that is the problem you should set proper timezone in the JS plugin that is showing the date